Why does "TimeValue()" Excel worksheet function not work on value "09:21:50.0558"?
I'm working with timestamps, containing milliseconds, like "09:21:50.0558".
According to this highly upvoted answer, the Excel worksheet function should be able to cope with such an input value but it doesn't: I get a #Value! error:

What do I need to do in order to get my Excel's TimeValue() worksheet function work with such timestamps?
I'm working with Excel 365, version 2403.
My Locale is Dutch, Belgium, but when I change this into English, United Kingdom, that does not change anything.

@MayukhBhattacharya: how can I multiply a value which can't be calculated itself? I'm already having a problem while performing =TimeValue(...) :-)

I am not saying, its the high voltage answer answer says.

@MayukhBhattacharya: ... but also =B2*86400000 gives a #VALUE! error value :-)

My problem comes down to the fact that my computer does not understand "09:21:50.0558" as a timestamp notation, while the PC of the answerer of that other question seems to be capable of understanding this timestamp format.

Tried it out as well, the weird thing I encountered: using =TIMEVALUE(B1) gives #value error, using =TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT("B1")) and '=TIMEVALUE("09:21:50.0558") both work. EDIT; somehow the indirect method fails now when I tried again.

@Excellor: thanks for the testing, here not one of your attempts seems to be working.

Can I ask what data type is the value at b2? According to microsoft - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-timevalue-function-d2a5e995-3586-4611-93a7-acfc7766dfff  - the value for timevalue needs to be a text not a number or a time.
What does =type(b2) return for you?

@bdpolinsky: the result of =Type(B2) equals 2, which seems to mean Text.

Well, for a locale of Dutch/Belgium you would have to change the dot to a comma; perhaps something went wrong in changing it to English? Have you tried using a comma? Both the direct and the INDIRECT formula work for me when using a comma.

In my locale (UK) timevalue does work without error but as far as I can tell it rounds the milliseconds to three significant figures, i.e. 9:21:50.056 in your first example. This leads me to think that it might be necessary to split the string to get an accurate answer, but even then you can't display it very easily because hh:mm:ss.0000 isn't a valid format.

Changing the Office-Display Language doesn't change the decimal separator, i.e. how about =TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",",")) ?

@SpectralInstance: sorry, I just saw your comment. You are right: replacing the dot by a comma indeed saves the day!

You may have to do something like this, which I know is ugly:
=LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(A2,"."),millis,TAKE(split,,-1),TIMEVALUE(@split)+millis/(86400*10^LEN(millis)))

And then to display it:
=TEXT(B2,"hh:mm:ss")&TEXT(MOD(B2,1/86400)*86400,".0000")


Before someone corrects me on this, these are decimilliseconds rather than milliseconds!

With an apostrophe to define as text and using comma for decimal separator it works in this way

Or  this formula also works:
=TEXT(I15;"@")   in this case I15 formatting as general and the apostrophe is not necessary.

=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"[$-en-US]h:mm:ss.000"))

Pasting as text doesn't seem to give different result when I tested. Wonder  whether specifying locale setting is helpful. Also, how significant is the 'lossy' result in your requirement?
Pardon me if this is not helpful.


The whole problem was indeed caused by a locale setting (the decimal separator not being recognised). This is the simplest way to solve it (don't laugh):
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";","))

